# When runing a Node.JS app from WHM/cPanel Application Manager, the Passenger file is missing "PassengerStartupFile" and won't actually run

Tags: node.js, cpanel, passenger

I've installed Node.JS via cPanel and all the Phusion Passenger files and dependencies. I can run the application manually via SSH. I have created the application in cPanel's Application Manager. However, after the application is "enabled" it's not actually "running" and only results in the Passenger error page.  It says it was not able to execute the application.

If I manually inspect the application configuration file in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/username/subdomain/application_name.conf` I can see it doesn't have an entry for `PassengerStartupFile`.  If I add the line

`PassengerStartupFile ./bin/www`

and restart the Passenger service, is works and I can access it via the URL.  However, if I disable and re-enable the application via cPanel, the conf file is regenerated and that entry is lost.

How can I get cPanel to add the `PassengerStartupFile` entry, or get Passenger to auto-detect the startup file from the `package.json` file or environment variables or something?

As a work-around, I've created a second `application_name_patch.conf` file with the missing configuration line so that it all eventually gets compiled together, but that's kludgy...

Answer (score 2):

Your solution to add a second `application_name_patch.conf` file next to the `appliation_name.conf` file is exactly the solution you need as is explained here: [How to Install a Node.js Application](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application#HowtoInstallaNode.jsApplication-Createacustomstartupfile.).

The linked article suggests you use the path `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/user/domain.nodejs.conf` for the custom startup file, but I would recommend you use the path `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/user/domain/nodejs.conf` as this will place the custom configuration in the same directory as the original application conf file.